# How to update multiple RasberryPi3 from the client?

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3

Currently, I have multiple RasberryPi3 devices that contains an app that will be used by my friends.
But the problem is how is it possible to update the app for each RasberryPi's ? I was thinking of sending the broadcast packets to the ports of the RasberryPis, but I'm not sure even if it's possible. Since I'm a total noob with RasberryPi,some tips, examples or tutorials would be a great help! I would love to hear from you!

Answer (score 1):

You could try to connect to each of them via SSH, but if they are all in different locations they'd need to set up some kind of port forwarding and give the ports and IP addresses. That would be a major pain.

If you didn't plan for software updates before you installed, you are rather out of luck.

You could try packaging in pip or some other package manager, say to work with apt-get. If the program was in python you could try pip and then publish it.

Or you, make an updater program that downloads the latest version from your website and installs it.

Comment: Are there some tutorials on updater programs ? I'm a total noob, so some simple stuffs will be a help!